# Can't push VisualForce page calling flow

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, visual-workflow

I have a visual force page that calls a flow and passes a quote Id as a parameter. When I run source:push to deploy the VFP and the Flow to a scratch org I get the following error:

> force-app\main\default\pages\VFP.page - No variable named "QuoteId" in flow.

If I push the Flow first by moving my Pages folder and then push the VFP after, everything works fine.

Is there a way to push both at once? Otherwise I cannot create a package verison.

**Flow variable:**

```
    <variables>
        <name>QuoteId</name>
        <dataType>String</dataType>
        <isCollection>false</isCollection>
        <isInput>true</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
    </variables>
```

**Visual Force Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" tabStyle="Quote" >
    <flow:interview name="Flow_Name" finishLocation="/{!Quote.Id}">
        <apex:param name="QuoteId" value="{!Quote.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I was not able to solve this. I had to refactor and call the flow directly without the VFP

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli . Seems like a bug to be reported to salesforce on cli .